# Where to put "non-bower" components

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm a newbie to nodejs and bower. I've just created angular projects with yeoman and see the bower_components folder. But if i have components/libraries that is not installed using bower, where should i put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put them in the `scripts` folder with in a subfolder `thirdparty`or `libraries`or whatever fits best for you.

Make sure that the libraries are minified with the main scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The questions then is: where do they come from then? There should not be any packages not handled by some package system.

Do you do this because the author did not publish the library in Bower registry? Bower can install packages from any git endpoint without registering them before:

```
bower install git://github.com/user/package.git
```

It could even handle "static" files if they are available on a URL:

```
bower install http://example.com/script.js
```

Plus, content of a *zip* or a *tar* will be extracted.

For more see the [docs](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install) (where the examples were taken).

In the rare event that the dependency cannot still be handled via Bower, I would recommend a folder usually called `lib` or `vendor` to be placed to the exact same level as `bower_components`.

Answer (score 0):

I put all my 3rd party script in a "vendor" folder both my bower libraries and the ones not installed with bower. Only difference is that I add non bower libraries to source control.